# Set a Job Name to Flink job using Table API

Tags: apache-flink

I want to set up a Job Name for my Flink application written using Table API, like I did it using Streaming API `env.execute(jobName)`.

**I want to replace:**

[image]

I can't find a way in documentation except to do it while running a job from **jar**

```
bin/flink run -d -yD pipeline.name=MyPipelineName-v1.0 ...
```

- **flink:** 1.14.5
- **env:** Yarn

**Update:**

In case someone will face the same situation. We can add Table API pipelines to Data Stream API [Doc](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.14/docs/dev/table/data_stream_api/#adding-table-api-pipelines-to-datastream-api), so doing like that will allow us to have a desired job name set programmatically.

Ex.:

```
    val sinkDescriptor = TableDescriptor.forConnector("kafka")
        .option("topic","topic_out")
        .option("properties.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092")
        .schema(schema)
        .format(FormatDescriptor.forFormat("avro").build())
        .build()

    tEnv.createTemporaryTable("OutputTable", sinkDescriptor)

    statementSet.addInsert(sinkDescriptor, tA)
    statementSet.attachAsDataStream()

    env.execute(jobName)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only StreamExecutionEnvironment calls `setJobName` on the stream graph.

Comment: Thanks David, I hope it will be changed one day because it's not very intuitive way for monitoring multiple Flink jobs.